# passing multiple args into npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line

I have a command line script in `package.json` file.

```
"entity:create": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm entity:create",
```

Now I need to pass in two flags into this script `-n` and `-d`.
This flags should be run like below

```
npm run entity:create -n User -d src
```

But since there are multiple command line args in here, I am not able to pass this in correctly.

Is there a way I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script)

> Any positional arguments are passed to the specified script. Use -- to pass --prefixed flags and options which would otherwise be parsed by npm.

```
npm run entity:create -- -n User -d src
```

Comment: How do I update my package json now, to take this args that I am passing in from terminal?

Comment: I guess you don't need to update anything else. it will resolved to `... typeorm entity:create -n User -d src` which should work according to [create-a-new-entity](https://typeorm.io/#/using-cli/create-a-new-entity) and [If you need to pass parameter with dash to npm script](https://typeorm.io/#/using-cli/if-entities-files-are-in-typescript)